# Why use an autoloader class over autoloader functions?

Tags: php

PHP has a built-in autoloader register, spl_autoloader_register(), where you can write your own autoloader functions, like I did below (any improvisations you can think of would be helpful):

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../libraries/global.lib.php');

            function load_classes($class) { // appears to get all the names of the classes that are needed in this script...
              $file_name = __DIR__ . '/classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
              if (file_exists($file_name)) {
                require_once($file_name);
              }
            }

            function load_interfaces($interface) {
              $file_name = __DIR__ . '/classes/' . $interface . '.interface.php';
              if (file_exists($file_name)) {
                require_once($file_name);
              }
            }

            spl_autoload_register('load_interfaces');
            spl_autoload_register('load_classes');

?>
```

But I started looking at other code and saw that people use an autoloader class instead of the built-in PHP autoloader functions: why is this?

Comment: Even if someone is using an autoloader object it is still registered using the built in autoloader functions, so it is not "instead of".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation on autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php):

> **Tip** spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

So the answer is actually that you're doing it the recommended way. The code you're looking at may be legacy, since `__autoload()` was available before `spl_autoload_register()`.

Note that you can also use static class functions for autoloading, if you want to go OO as much as possible:

```
class MyClass {
    static function myloader($name) {
        require_once($name.'.php');
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('MyClass::myloader');
```